# Why did Darcy Banker ask the man in the Green Room to give up his gun?

Tags: plot-explanation, green-room

In Green Room, the young people are stuck in the room with a man who's got a gun. Darcy Banker (played by Patrick Stewart) shows up and is ready to kill them, presumably using knives so they can make it look like the dogs got them.

The obvious approach then is to tell the man with the gun to open the door, come out, and then the guys with the knives can enter and let loose.

However, Darcy tells him to *give the gun to the young people*. They then take the gun and do exactly what you would expect them to do: refuse to leave the room, holding the man at gun point. Suddenly things are much more complicated for Patrick Stewart and his crew.

Why - in the world - did he tell the man to give his gun away?

Is there a possible in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/4i8038/official_discussion_green_room_spoilers/d3805lg/ "Darcy gave up the gun to instill some trust. At that point he had already cooked up the plan to murder them and stage their deaths. But by giving away the gun Darcy was hoping to get them out of the green room to kill them quickly, easily, and without jeopardizing Big Justin, who was still in the room with them, stomach intact."

Comment: @BCdotWEB Any reservations to using the answer section over the comment section for answers?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I haven't seen the movie, so I don't know whether it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Darcy knows that the band are just a bunch of kids who are out of their depth and just want to get out without anyone else being hurt.  Giving up the gun instils trust and he's confident they wont use it, at least not right away, so it de-escalates the situation and buys him time to corral his forces.  In fact, if I remember correctly, he later argues that  even with the gun, the band's position is almost hopeless, that their only hope of getting out is to give up the gun, which they eventually agree to do, with the bullets removed.